# In JavaScript are strings arrays-like objects?

Tags: javascript

Strings in JavaScript have a length property like arrays, but they don't have methods such as `forEach` or `reduce`.

Does this mean that strings are array-like objects?

Comment: No, in JS strings are primitives. In order to use the string methods, a temporary object is created.

Comment: Notice, that there are some methods in [String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype) too ...

Answer (score 13):

The term "array-like" usually refers to an object having an integer-valued `.length` property and correspondingly many elements stored in integer-keyed properties, so that we can access them by index like an array. Strings certainly fulfill that requirement.

No, strings do not have all the methods that arrays have. They don't inherit from `Array.prototype`, they are not real arrays - they're just array-*like*. You can however trivially convert a string to an array, either by `….split('')` or by `Array.from(…)`.

Comment: Hmmm, now I'm confused. You are saying that strings are array-like but @Teemu is saying that they aren't (please see the very first comment).

Comment: @user1941537 Normal strings are no objects (that's what Teemu said), but they still are array-like. When you access a property on a primitive value, it does get implicitly coerced to a temporary object though

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation these functions does not exist ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)).

But you can add functions to the `String` prototype

```
// forEach function
String.prototype.forEach = function (f) {
  for (i=0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    f(this[i]);
  }
}


// reduce function
String.prototype.reduce = function (f, start) {
  result = (start == undefined) ? null : start
  for(i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    result += f(this[i])
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In javaScript the string letters are get stored in the indexed manner,both primitive as well as the object type string get stored in the indexed value of the string reference name.
Then a question come to mind that why we convert string to array in javaScript,well if we want to sort the letters we need sort method which javaScript array consist.String contain no sort method.Sting contain some property like length,but srting does not contain all the methods an Array contain.
If we apply sort method in string it give an error that "stringName.sort is not a function".